# Hashtags in database

Tags: php, mysqli, hashtag

I'm curious to know how I could select anything in my database with a #tag and show it in any page I like. As I'm wanting to show all tags made by other users and then will also extend on it of the, "you may also like..."

I've tried:

```
$text = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9_]#i', '','');

 $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM blogdata_comments WHERE comment_content LIKE '%#$text%' ORDER BY comment_id DESC");

echo"<a style='color:#0000FF;' href='hash.php?tag=$text'>$text</a>";
```

Comment: Your third argument to preg_replace should be an actual string, ideally the one you want to use in your query. Right now $text will always be ''

Comment: But I don't need the one hashtag through $_GET['tag'] i need to get any tagged word in the database..

Comment: If you want all comment_content rows with the hash, you would use LIKE '%#%' is that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you @xd6_. Sorry it took so long to reply, but I've been working. Works fine.